# BlazBlue CSE: How do team battles work?

Tags: blazblue-continuum-shift-extend

*BlazBlue: Continuum Shift Extend* just came out in Japan and there are supposed to be "team battles" in it.

http://www.dualshockers.com/2011/12/01/blazblue-continuum-shift-extend-european-release-window-revealed/

> team battles featuring 2v2, 3v3, 4v4

How does this work exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this [video](http://www.nicovideo.jp/watch/1324031418) (Sorry, no skipping. you'll have to let it load). At ~12:03 they explain the tag team battles (in Japanese, sorry :p).

When you're in a player match room (under Network mode), on the right hand side of room info bar (above the list of players) are two icons, a 3v3-type icon and a heart shaped icon. Those are your battle/match types. In the former, each team member fights one opponent and side with the most wins will be the winner. The latter is legion style, where the winner recovers a set amount of health after every match. In the room, you can use the Left Trigger to do simple preset chat commands.

Select your screen name and choose your team here (red or blue diamond) with the Left and Right buttons or with the analog stick. Then set yourself as ready for a match (Circle on the JP PS3 toggles the ready ["OK"] and not ready [no "OK" icon] status next to your name). Everyone in the room has to do this and when everyone is ready, the character select screen will load.

At the character select screen, after you've selected your character, you can use the simple messaging (Left Trigger) to coordinate the order your team members fight in and then select the order you play in (the order number goes to the first player that selects it) or choose the option to randomly select your order (this should be the only option that's not a number).

You will then see the match ups and the first match will now commence.

Comment: So is this available offline? Can the CPU play on team battles?

Comment: It's just the online mode that was adjusted. You can just swap controllers offline if you want to do the same. As in CPU vs. CPU? No. You can have 1 vs. 3 team battles though.

Comment: I meant like 1 human + 2 CPU vs 2 Human + 1 CPU?

Comment: No. Players only.